# Prompting for a double and reading in until user has correctly entered a floating point number

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I don't quite understand this question. It wants me to write a code that prompts for and reads a double and repeats that process until the user has correctly entered a floating point number.

Isn't `double` a type of `floating point`? So how would this code end?

EDIT - Ok, so maybe the program needs to take in a double and continue doing so until the value entered is a float. This means, as long as the precision of the input is in the range of a double, but not of a float, it will continue taking input. However, if the precision of the input is within that of a float, the program ends. Does this seem correct?

Comment: and where is the code??

Comment: It would end when the user has correctly entered a floating point number, as the question implies. My guess (and this is just a guess because this sounds like homework), is that it's accepting any unfiltered input from console, and it wants you to avoid some user entering anything other than a floating point number (of double precision)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I *really* don't think that's what the assignment means, but post it verbatim if you want a fully-formed opinion. It would be very bizarre for an assignment to use the phrase "floating point number" to mean specifically a value in the range of the type `float`. It's true that `float`s are floating point numbers, but it is also true that `double`s are floating point numbers. Basically, `double` is short for "double precision floating point number", and `float` is short for "single precision floating point number".

Comment: So I think the things you're supposed to reject look like `hi there, I'm a cat walking across the keybdyfdiofdufdfsd`, rather than looking like `1.0e+39`.

Comment: @SteveJessop What I have is pretty much it, but here it is verbatim: "Write code that prompts for and reads a double, repeating until the user has correctly entered a floating-point number. Your program should handle input that is not a number by printing an error message, correcting the situation, and prompting again." I didn't ask about the second part as I understand how to do that.

Comment: @Gundown64: OK, my fully-formed opinion is that for that specification you should accept the input `1e+39`, even though it doesn't fit in a `float`. "a floating-point number" is being used in the assignment as a synonym for "input that represents a `double`". And if that's not what's intended, hey, I'm prepared to tell your teacher that they're wrong ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Alright so what does "repeating until the user has correctly entered a floating-point number" mean. How does the program terminate?

Comment: @Gundown64: you should terminate immediately after you read a floating-point number from `stdin`, as opposed to reading something from `stdin` that is not a floating-point number. That is to say, when you detect the condition that you *don't* need to print an error message and repeat. Or are you asking how to terminate a program? In which case I think returning from `main` is acceptable: even if your professor has used the word "terminate" in relation to programs finishing, I very much doubt that specifically means `std::terminate()`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ok, I think just the wording of the problem is really awkward. Basically, the way I was reading it was "Ask for and read a number (double in this case) and continue asking for a number until the input is a number (float). Output an error if not a number." This obviously makes no sense because as long as the input is a number within the range of a double the program wants to repeat, but also wants to terminate. Does that make sense? It looks like what you are saying is the program terminates as soon as a double (or float) is entered, but the program is supposed to repeat right?

Comment: The program repeats only if the user *doesn't* enter a floating-point number. But I see your point, the first sentence of the assignment is syntactically identical to "Write code that prompts for and reads a double, repeating until the user enters 12". So it might be a little surprising that in the assignment the clause after "repeating until" is in fact true whenever the user has actually entered the double you asked for. I think it could be improved, "Write code that prompts for and *attempts* to read a double, repeating until it succeeds in reading a double".

Comment: Ah, ok, then that is a fairly simple program. Ask for a double. If it is a double then terminate. If not, output error and ask again until a double is input. That wording was just not great I guess. Thanks or your help @SteveJessop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading a formatted value fails, the stream goes into failure mode, i.e., it gets `std::ios_base::failbit` set. Once it is in failure mode, the stream won't accept any further input until it's state gets `clear()`ed. Once it is cleared, the bad input needs to be discarded. One way to do so is to `ignore()` all characters until the end of the line. The corresponding could would look like this:

```
double value(0);
while (!(std::cin >> value) && !std::cin.eof()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::stremsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

If the input on the given line should not contain any garbage, e.g., consider input of the format `12.3x` broken, the condition can be extended to check if there is some other character on the line:

```
while ((!(std::cin >> value) || std::cin.peek() != '\n') && !std::cin.eof()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This code does accept `1.0 garbage`, though, and it might be the intent of the assignment to reject that. Hard to say for sure, since "user has correctly entered a floating point number" is a bit under-specified.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree with this assessment but I wouldn't read the request to detect if there is garbage.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Sadly, that code is just slightly over my head as I am currently in the process of learning about streams, eof, and all that. Could this possibly be done a little simper?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `boost` your function that checks the input (which is in a string) would look like this:

```
static bool isCorrect( const std::string& value )
{
    try
    {
        boost::lexical_cast< double >( value ) ; /* this code only checks */
        return true ;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << value << " argument is not double!" << std::endl ;
        return false ;
    }
}
```

If you cannot use any other library then you need to parse string to see if the string contains digits, an optional dot, and then digits, and if your requirements ask for E type format then if it is followed by E and digits. For this you need to write a parser, and that would be the real requirement you received. This requirement is intended to teach you to write a parser rather than to deliver a code, so I will leave it for you to do.

Comment: There will be a time in which writing C++ code that catches everything and swallows will be punished with jail.

Comment: @6502 OMG. this made me laugh

Comment: @6502 :D Unless you care for false/true result.

Comment: @Grzegorz that doesn't mean you should catch *everything*.

Comment: @DavidBrown Why do you think, David, I should not catch in this case? Please send me to the proper material, and I would love to learn about it more.

Comment: Specifically, one might be concerned whether `lexical_cast` can throw `std::bad_alloc` or something, rather than the `bad_lexical_cast` assumed by the error message. Granted it seems unlikely that your program would last long if that did happen, but it's the principle of the thing, you shouldn't really make a habit of imprecise error-handling.